# An equivalent condition for a real matrix to be skew-symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is an $n \times n$ real matrix.

prove that

$$A=-A^T \iff AA^T=-A^2$$.

Thanks.

Comment: One implication is immediate. Where are you stuck on the other direction?

Comment: Actually I just don't know how to start.Whatever I try,It will require that A is inventible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a proof for the nontrivial direction, right to left in the question.  Like any real square matrix, $A$ can be represented as the sum $A=S+G$ of a symmetric matrix $S=(A+A^T)/2$ and an antisymmetric matrix $G=(A-A^T)/2$.  The given equation $AA^T=-A^2$ can be rewritten as $(S+G)S=0$ or $S^2+GS=0$. Our task is to prove that $S=0$.  Suppose not. By the spectral theorem, $S$ has a non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$; let $v$ be a column eigenvector.  So $v\neq0$ and $Sv=\lambda v$.  Therefore $S^2v=\lambda^2v$ and, since $S^2+GS=0$, we get 
$$
\lambda Gv=G(\lambda v)=GSv=-S^2v=-\lambda^2v.
$$
As $\lambda\neq0$, we infer $Gv=-\lambda v$.  Using this, we compute
$$
\lambda v^Tv=-v^TGv=+v^TG^Tv=(Gv)^Tv=-\lambda v^Tv,
$$
where the second equality uses that $G$ is antisymmetric.  So $2\lambda v^Tv=0$.  But this is absurd, since $\lambda$ and $v^Tv$ (and 2) are non-zero.

Comment: To Andreas Blass:  that is just *so cute*!  Very well done indeed, sir!  Way cool, +1!

Comment: I've never know  the spectral theorem util now.This answer showed me what it is and how to use it.Thanks.