# If $A=AA^{\top}$, show that $A^2=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been working trying to understand the following question:

Let n be a positive integer, let $F$ be a field, and let $A \in \mathrm{Mat}(n,F)$ satisfy the condition $A=AA^{\top}$. Show that $A^2=A$.

I haven't made much progress since my knowledge is pretty basic but I ran across this link and was wondering if this example was essentially the same?

[Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571583/if-matrix-such-aat-a2-then-a-is-symmetric)

Comment: If $A=A A^T$, can you express $A^T$?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since $A^T = (AA^T)^T = AA^T = A$, You have $A^2 = AA = AA^T = A$

Comment: I follow the A^T til =A, the first part.Then A^2=AA but how does AA=AA^T?

Comment: Use the fact $A^T = A$ to substitute $A^T$ for the second $A$ in $AA$.

Comment: oh, ok. I figured it was something plain as day. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

get transpose from $A=AA^T$ thus we have $A^T=AA^T$ and thus we have $A=A^T$ and it proved that $A=A^2$

Answer (score -1):

$AA^T=A$

$A$ from the LHS to the RHS

$A^T=AA^{-1} \Rightarrow A^T=I\Rightarrow A=I$

$I^2=I \Rightarrow A^2=A$

**Edit:** It works only, if $det \ A\neq 0$

Comment: Consider $A=0$, which has no inverse.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I didn´t think of this case.

Comment: And $A^2 = A$ in the special case $A = 0$ too, although not via the exact same reasoning.