# Let $A$ be a complex matrix and $AA^t=A^2$, is it always right that $A$ is symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is a well-known result that when $A$ is a real matrix and $AA^t=A^2$ then $A$ is symmetric. I guess the same proposition is right for a complex matrix, but I can't prove it. Could someone give me some hints on this problem? I will be very appreciated for your help!

Comment: My guess is that this is not true unless you use a conjugate transpose. Try and construct some $2 \times 2$ examples.

Comment: Did you inspect the proof of this statement. Does it really rely on the fact that the entries are real? And if yes, what are modifications you could/should assume?

Comment: Try $A\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ with $a_{12}=i$ and $a_{21}=?$

Comment: At least this is correct for invertible $A$.

Comment: The claim is correct for $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: Thanks for your warm replies. I can prove it by elementary algebra when the order of $A$ is 2, or 3. As Friedrich said, this holds for invertible $A$. And we have known this also holds for real A. So, based on some algebraic geometry consideration, I am strongly prone to its rightness.

Comment: Most of the proofs here don't rely on the entries being real. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571583/if-matrix-such-aat-a2-then-a-is-symmetric?rq=1 so it is true for all complex matrices.

Comment: @ Wintermute, thanks for your link, I will read it right now!

Comment: The entries here are **not** assumed to be real, in contrast to the matrices in the link.

Comment: oh, i have read that article before. The proofs there are all depending on the condition of $A$ being real.

Comment: At least one can prove that $AA^T = A^TA$. Does this help?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp, thanks for your hint. Maybe i need a new try under this.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: Is it immediate that $A A^* = A^* A$?

Comment: @copper.hat No, because it's wrong. I don't know what I did yesterday... :-( Daniel's answer gives a counterexample.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: Well, that example shows that $A A^T =A^2$ does not allow us to conclude that $A$ is symmetric, but I imagine that $A A^* =A^2$ would imply that $A$is Hermitian.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes. Take the second answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571583/if-matrix-such-aat-a2-then-a-is-symmetric?rq=1 You can almost copy it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, $n\geq 3$.

A very simple counterxample is the following:

Let $v^t=(0,0,1,0,...,0)$ and $w^t=(1,i,0,...,0)$.

Notice that $w^tw=1+i^2=0$ and $w^tv=0$. Define $A=vw^t$.

Now, $A^2=(w^tv)A=0$ and $AA^t=(w^tw)vv^t=0$, but $A=vw^t\neq w^tv=A^t$.

Comment: How do you get $A^2=(w^tv)A$ and $AA^t=(w^tw)vv^t$?

Comment: Hi @Wojowu , $A^2=v(w^tv)w^t=(w^tv)vw^t=(w^tv)A$ and $AA^t=v(w^tw)v^t=(w^tw)vv^t$

Comment: Ah, right, $w^tv$ and $w^tw$ are scalars, so they commute with all matrices.

Comment: @Daniel, very great anwser! Thanks a lot  for your enthusiastic help!

Comment: @MarcLee You are welcome